# Multiple columns updation in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can I update two columns in different tables with single update query.
I stuck in a situation where I have :

Table 1:

```
case id    client id   created by
1           a          john  
2           b          Mike   
3           c          Raghu
4           b          Mike
```

Table 2:

```
case id    client id     case cost
2           b             5,000
3           j            10,000
4           b             6,000
```

The problem is , I want to update client id=d in both the tables of those cases created by Mike.

I can fetch out those cases through join which is created by mike but is it possible to update them also by using sql joins??

Comment: It depends on the database you are using.  Please update your question with the database tag.

Comment: I am using Sql database; that's 2012

Comment: **Sql database** , is that MS SQL , MYSQL , etc .. ?

Comment: SQL Server (including 2012) only allows a single update statement to affect a single row.  So you can you do this only in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to more updates in one statement is no. While you can enter multiple tables in the from clause of an update statement, you can only specify a single table after the update keyword. Even if you do write a "updatable" view (which is simply a view that follows certain restrictions), updates like this will fail. 

To fix this
**Use transaction block:**

Example :

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    update A
    set A.client_id =  'd'
    from table1 A inner join table2 B
    on B.client_id = A.client_id
where a.created_by='mike'

    update B
    set B.client_id = 'd'
    from table2 B inner join table1 A
        on B.client_id = A.client_id
        where a.created_by='mike'


    COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this will work

```
UPDATE table1,table2 SET table1.client_id='d',table2.client_id='d'
WHERE table1.client_id=table2.client_id;
```

Since you mentioned RDBMS as MSSQL 2012; you can have only single update statement.
You can either have multiple in transaction block as mentioned in another answer (OR)

Create a procedure and wrap both your update statement there like

```
create procedure update_table1_table2
as 
begin
UPDATE table1 SET client_id='d' WHERE client_id='b';
UPDATE table2 SET client_id='d' WHERE client_id='b';
end
```

Then call your procedure like

```
exec update_table1_table2
```

Comment: Nope, not valid in MSSQL 2012

Comment: Is OP using MSSQL? OK, Answer is given prior it's been tagged.